# Combinatorial testing with Cucumber

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

I have a scenario outline that has two different variables. One variable has about 20 different values and the other has 3.

I need to be able to test every single combination and I need each in a separate scenario since they must be tested independently.

Currently, I just write it out by hand(they are integers in the example but not in my test):

```
Scenario Outline: Test my stuff
Given first var is <var_a>
And second var is <var_b>
When I do stuff
Then good stuff should happen

Examples:
| var_a | var_b |
| 1     | 1     |
| 1     | 2     |
| 1     | 3     |
| 2     | 1     |
| 2     | 2     |
etc...
```

**Question:** Is there a way to run this where every combination doesn't have to be written out? The variables are bound to change in size and content later on and I would prefer to have a single data structure to deal with.

Comment: This sounds more like a unit test than a functional test, so I don't think cucumber is the best tool to use. If you're trying to test the layout, consider a javascript TDD tool, like QUnit. If you're trying to test model or controller logic, consider Test::Unit or RSpec. If you absolutely want to use cucumber, why not just abstract this into a step so that your stories are still readable?

Comment: @Ben - you should add this as an answer. This is a very legitimate point.

Comment: The tests are for a UI widget in a browser(using Watir). The reason I have so many combinations is because there are many ways to do the same thing. I tried RSpec before switching to Cucumber but I found it wasn't the right tool for what I was doing.

Comment: @ben could you expand on what you mean in the last sentence?

Comment: my last point was just that while the ability to define tables in the stories themselves is a cool feature of cucumber, I personally feel that gets in the way of the story. The story itself is something like, "Given I am a user, and I have entered in data to a table, then I should be able to sort that table in every possible way."  At least to me, that's quite readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scenario: Test my stuff
Given first var combinations is @var_a_combos
Given second var combinations is @var_b_combos
When I run every combination
Then good stuff should happen
```

- `@var_a_combos` and `@var_b_combos`
  are an Enumerable that contains every
  different possibility for that type.
- The `When I run every combination`
  will iterate over both variables and
  test every single combination.
  Instead of using an assertion, it
  will instead create a
  @results(String) variable that will
  list any failures and their required
  debugging data.
- The `Then good stuff should happen`
  will run the code `@results.should
  eql ""` to determine whether the test
  case passed/failed.

The purpose of using a String variable to hold the results(instead of an assertion) is to ensure that testing does not stop when the first failure is encountered.

**I really don't like this solution** but it is the best I could come up with so far. I appreciate the other answers but this testing really is integration testing and I really do need to test every combination.

If anyone posts further answers I will review them and change the accepted answer if I think it is better.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tests are for a UI widget, and you're trying to test it at the unit level, you should check out QUnit (or another javascript unit testing framework, but this one's my personal preference). You can even run QUnit tests via cucumber, as in [Test sorting with Cucumber and Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413865/test-sorting-with-cucumber-and-capybara)

Comment: I'll check out QUnit but the testing really isn't on the unit level. It's black box testing where interacting with the UI widget is one of the middle steps. Determining whether the test case passed comes later and is not browser based.

Comment: I stated several comments ago that the "tests are for a UI widget" but that wasn't exactly true. The variables I need to test in combination are for interacting with the UI widget, but the test isn't on the actual widget.

Comment: Writing good QUnit tests will actually force you to encapsulate the interactions in testable javascript functions, which will lead to better design and fewer bugs anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you really need to test every combination? Could you explain some context around the problem?

Anyway, regarding your query about running everything in a separate scenario, a Scenario Outline with examples is what you need. See the Cucumber docs.